# Iteration of an object, that may have parent, or child of it's own same type

Tags: c#, .net, oop, traversal

I have a class that may have a parent, or list of children of the same type of it's own. The following code snippet should explain my scenario.

```
public abstract class X{
    public virtual List<X> ChildItems { get; set; }
    public virtual X ParentItem { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to know if there is a particularly efficient method to traverse the objects from an object of type X, checking if the object has a parent, or children starting from bottom up.

```
public static void SaveSetup(X obj) { 
     //logic here
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to achieve? Are you trying to identify the top level object or something?

Comment: See this [TPL for traversing the tree from leaves/branches to root](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/da-DK/parallelextensions/thread/91b0e5a9-6cdd-4e5b-81fc-51c34defd046)

Comment: Traversing all elements within an object of type X is what I am after. And an efficient method. What ssl specified seems to be the right direction.

@sll I am going to try your link, as it seems that is very similar to what I am after. Will get back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are dealing with is a tree structure (or possibly many disconnected tree structures). A tree structure has a root element. Usually, a tree structure is traversed starting from the root. If you want to start from any element in the tree, I suggest you to first get the root element and then traverse in the usual manner.

The easiest way to traverse a recursive structure is to use recursive method, i.e., a method that calls itself.

```
public abstract class X
{
    public virtual List<X> ChildItems { get; set; }
    public virtual X ParentItem { get; set; }

    // Method for traversing from top to bottom
    public void Traverse(Action<X> action)
    {
        action(this);
        foreach (X item in ChildItems) {
            item.Traverse(action);
        }
    }

    // Get the root (the top) of the tree starting at any item.
    public X GetRootItem()
    {
        X root = this;
        while (root.ParentItem != null) {
            root = root.ParentItem;
        }
        return root;
    }
}
```

Now you can save the setup with

```
X root = item.GetRootItem();
root.Traverse(SaveSetup);
```

Example with lambda expression. Prints every item of the tree assuming that `ToString()` has been overridden to return a meaningful string.

```
root.Traverse(x => Console.WriteLine(x));
```

Comment: This is exactly the direction I was after. After changing a little bit the code, to suit my original scenario, it worked efficiently, and correct. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Traverse from given object to root (ParentItem = null)

```
public static void SaveSetup(X obj) { 
    while (obj != null)
    {
      // logic here
      obj = obj.ParentItem;
    }
}
```

Comment: then you're missing it's siblings (and uncles and cousins and nephews)

Comment: Sorry if the question was not clear enough.

Let me explain in a scenario. For instance, I want to setup a tree hierarchy of a branch small markets. Each market, can have a parent market, and also several child markets. So when I want to load a market I can see both things which are:

1)Who he/she belongs to
2)What other markets fall under this specified market

So object X, would be market. But a market can own many mini-markets, and have a parent which he/she falls under.

Hope this clears some things :-)